# MySQL PROCEDURE query not working properly

Tags: mysql, procedure

pls help me. I try to create a MySql PROCEDURE:

```
    DELIMITER $$
Create Procedure hethan(IN ngay INT)
        BEGIN
            select *from sanphamdung WHERE sanphamdung.ngayhethan <>' ' and STR_TO_DATE(sanphamdung.ngayhethan, '%d/%m/%Y') < CURDATE() + INTERVAL ngay DAY;
        END;
    $$DELIMITER ;
```

The test record: '10/02/2018'; I called this procedure:

```
CALL hethan(1);=>got error
CALL hethan(10);=> working properly
```

My select is working. My function return right result when my select returns some records but, if my select returns empty (no record), my function get error:

```
Error
SQL query: Edit Edit


    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;
    MySQL said: Documentation

    #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

What wrong? thank you. 
p/s: sanphamdung.ngayhethan is varchar, example: "06/02/2018"

Comment: any one help me :(

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/szLu8yb3PCtKuL9rqbiGFN/0).

Comment: @wchiquito opps, why???

Comment: "sql query: edit edit" is no message that mysql will give you, nor is "set foreign_key_checks" part of your procedure. You have some code that calls your procedure. The error lies there. You will have to add that code to your question (or check if for yourself).